# Rsnapshot without hard links?

Tags: backup, hardlink

I'm using Rsnapshot to backup all my servers on an EncFS encrypted partition. The partition has been created with the default `paranoia` mode offered by EncFS, thus it doesn't support hard links.

I'm able to run Rsnapshot the first time (creating `daily.0`, `weekly.0`, `monthly.0`) but not the second time.

Is there a way to use Rsnapshot without the hardlinking feature? I know it sounds a bit silly, but my `rsnapshot.conf` is very well configured and I don't want either to switch to another software or erase and recreate the EncFS volume.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Look for this section in */etc/rsnapshot.conf* file:

```
# If your version of rsync supports --link-dest, consider enable this.
# This is the best way to support special files (FIFOs, etc) cross-platform.
# The default is 0 (off).
#
#link_dest  0
```

Make sure the "link_dest" is disabled. This is used as a flag when rsync command is called in the background. As per the man page for rsync:

```
--link-dest=DIR         hardlink to files in DIR when unchanged
```

Comment: If anything `--link-dest` should be enabled not disabled (its disabled by default). By default rsnapshot will use `cp -al <backup1> <backup2>` for rotation on the encfs filesystem, which the OP is saying will break because of encfs settings. Enabling `--link-dest` in my testing seems to use `mv <backup0> <backup1>` instead, which may fix the issue.

Comment: I tried this and now I am getting failed to hard link :/ any ideas?